# TinyMCE not working on Virtual Host?

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, virtualhost

I am have a project to make WYSIWYG Editor for my website dashboard. So I am already have somekind script to worked on server. Ex: [natabuana.com/editor](http://natabuana.com/editor)
And when I am trying the same file on localhost, it's turn to be white page, Why this happen ?
CORECTION : on this address `http://localhost/editor.php` look like it's work as usual. And NOT working on this address `http://www.natabuana.com/editor.php (still on localhost)`

The problem is I am using Virtual Host to stimulate real web address into my project, So maybe problem is about `Javascript / JQuery on Apache Virtual Host`...

Comment: If you use firefox, check thefirebug console..

Comment: nothing error show on firebug

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that your tinymce initialisation takes place before a html dom element is loaded. Use this to make it work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <title>JS Rich-Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:fantasy">
    <h1>TinyMCE Getting Started Guide</h1>
    <form method="post" action="editor.php">
    <textarea id="mytextarea" name="content" style="height:256px"></textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({ selector: "#mytextarea", menubar:false , plugins: "table image link code", tools: "inserttable", fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt", toolbar: ["code | fontselect | fontsizeselect | bold italic | link image | alignleft aligncenter alignright | table inserttable | undo redo" ] });
    </script>
</html>
```

Alternative:

if you use jQuery put your tinymce initalization into a document-ready call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({ selector: "#mytextarea", menubar:false , plugins: "table image link code", tools: "inserttable", fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt", toolbar: ["code | fontselect | fontsizeselect | bold italic | link image | alignleft aligncenter alignright | table inserttable | undo redo" ] });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is not working? do you get any errors? Can you create a ja fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) for this?

Comment: This is live sample and it's working [http://natabuana.com/editor](http://natabuana.com/editor). But when i recreate using xampp it's not working.

Comment: then the problem is somewhere else. do you get any errors (client- and/or serverside)?